# How merge many select statements

Tags: php, mysql

Following query:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE day1 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day2 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day3 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day4 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day5 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day6 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day7 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day8 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day9 = '$today' AND country = 'India' OR day10 = '$today' AND country = 'India'";
if($_POST!=""){
  $mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datepicker']);
  if($mydate!=""){  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE day1 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day2 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day3 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day4 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day5 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day6 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day7 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day8 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day9 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India' OR day10 = '$mydate' AND country = 'India'";   
  }     
}
.......
........
echo"......
......
......
```

Its linked with datepicker. Will echo in the same page only. Want to add the following select statement also in the same page....if user clicks "next 10 days programs".

```
select * from table WHERE (day1 >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   AND country = 'India'
   AND day1 <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 DAY
   AND country = 'India')
OR
   (day2 >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   AND country = 'India'
   AND day2 <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 DAY
   AND country = 'India')

......till day10
```

Comment: No need to repeat `country = 'India'`...

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Fix your database design or explain why you need 10 dates please.

Comment: This question has been asked at least twice by you. One of them can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757992/how-write-select-statement-to-pick-10-date-columns

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table 
 WHERE (
            (day1 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day2 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day3 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day4 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day5 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day6 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day7 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day8 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day9 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         OR (day10 BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
       )
   AND country = 'India'
```